# Pass context to pagination class in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, parameters, pagination, django-rest-framework

I have my custom pagination class.

```
class BasicPagination(PageNumberPagination):
 page_size = 3
 page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
 max_page_size = 20

 def get_paginated_response(self, data):
    has_next, has_previous = False, False
    if self.get_next_link():
        has_next = True
    if self.get_previous_link():
        has_previous = True

    meta = collections.OrderedDict([
        ('page', self.page.number),
        ('has_next', has_next),
        ('has_previous', has_previous),
    ])
    ret = collections.OrderedDict(meta=meta)
    ret["results"] = data
    return Response(ret)
```

Also I have a `generics.ListCreateAPIView` class, which has custom queryset method and `pagination_class = BasicPagination`. I wanna pass `self.kwargs.get("obj_type")` to pagination class so that it displays `obj_type` not `results`. Here is my class view. **How can I pass `self.kwargs` to pagination class?**

```
class Translation(ListCreateAPIView):

 pagination_class = BasicPagination
 serializer_class = TranslationStepSerializer

 def get_queryset(self):
    api_controller = ApiController.load()
    obj_type = self.kwargs.get("obj_type")
    pk = self.kwargs.get("pk")

    data = api_controller.get_translation(obj_type, pk)

    return data if not None else None
```

Comment: If I understand what you meant, maybe try to override the BasicPagination constructor that takes in an extra argument of obj_type, then make a return call to super(PageNumberPa). So on your query set method u can re-initalize your pagination_class and pass your obj_type.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that by this -

> it displays obj_type not results

you mean that you want the key in your response to be `obj_type` instead of "results". That is obj_type is a string in your code.

I had a similar requirement where I wanted to modify the response based on certain conditions. As a workaround, I added all the required parameters to `data` itself, through which I customised the paginated response.

```
def get_paginated_response(self, data):

    if self.get_next_link():
        next_page = data["page_no"] + 1
    else:
        next_page = 0

    response = {
        "next": next_page,
        'count': self.page.paginator.count,
        'cards': data["cards"],
        'companies': data["companies"],
        'positions': data["positions"],
        'cities':data["cities"]
    }

    tags =  data.get('tags', None)

    if tags is not None:
        response['tags'] = tags

    return Response(data=response)
```

In your case you can do something like:

```
ret[data['obj_type']] = data['results']
```

And prior to this, in the queryset:

```
data = {'results': api_controller.get_translation(obj_type, pk), 'obj_type': obj_type}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's late I know. But in your view-set you can override `get_paginated_response`  and `list` methods:

```
class Translation(ListCreateAPIView):

 pagination_class = BasicPagination
 serializer_class = TranslationStepSerializer

 def get_queryset(self):
    api_controller = ApiController.load()
    obj_type = self.kwargs.get("obj_type")
    pk = self.kwargs.get("pk")

    
    data = api_controller.get_translation(obj_type, pk)

    return data if not None else None
 
 def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data, extra_keys={'obj_type': self.kwargs.get("obj_type")})

    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

 def get_paginated_response(self, data, extra_keys):
    """
    Return a paginated style `Response` object for the given output data.
    """
    assert self.paginator is not None
    return self.paginator.get_paginated_response(data, extra_keys)
```

and in your pagination class you can get `extra_keys` as argument:

```
 class BasicPagination(PageNumberPagination):
     page_size = 3
     page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
     max_page_size = 20

     def get_paginated_response(self, data, extra_keys):

        # here you can get your passed keys 
        # for example for obj_type
        obj_type = extra_keys['obj_type']
        
        has_next, has_previous = False, False
        if self.get_next_link():
            has_next = True
        if self.get_previous_link():
            has_previous = True

        meta = collections.OrderedDict([
            ('page', self.page.number),
            ('has_next', has_next),
            ('has_previous', has_previous),
        ])
        ret = collections.OrderedDict(meta=meta)
        ret["results"] = data
        return Response(ret)
```

*Note*: I used dictinary to pass your variable because if there be another variables to pass this is neater. but you can simply just pass your desired variable.

Answer (score 0):

> **Here is Simple Approch to Pass extra data with to pagination class**

> paginations.py

```py
class ResultsSetPagination(LimitOffsetPagination):
    page_size = 50
    max_limit = 150
    offset_query_param = 'page'
    limit_query_param = 'limit'
    def get_paginated_response(self, data, **kwargs):
        
        # return Response({
        #     # 'data': data
        # })
        return { 
            'links': {
                'next': self.get_next_link(),
                'previous': self.get_previous_link()
                },
            'data': data
        }
```

> views.py

```py
def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            # return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
            return response.Response({
                'success': bool(queryset),
                **self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data),
                'extra': 'read.sanjaysikdar.dev'
            })
```

Feel free to ask.